# Return result with concatenated string

Tags: string, xquery, concatenation

I want to write a xquery statement that returns a number plus a string called " books". Like this:

```
<table>
<tr><td>300 books</td></tr>
<tr><td>145 books</td></tr>
</table>
```

I've started writing the code, but it doesn't work...

```
<tr><td>{$num + 'books'}</td>
```

Any help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the literal string " books" outside of the expression:

```
<tr><td>{$num} books</td></tr>
```

Or you could create a sequence of items by enclosing it inside of parenthesis and separating with a comma:

```
<tr><td>{($num, 'books')}</td></tr>
```

Or you could concatenate the items (notice the leading space):

```
<tr><td>{concat($num, ' books')}</td></tr>
```

Comment: Or, if you are using XQuery 3.0, you could do `<tr><td>{$num || ' books'}</td></tr>`